# No exporter for Kafka in Spring Boot Actuator

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, metrics, spring-boot-actuator

Is there any exporter to Kafka the same way Spring boot has for Redis (RedisMetricRepository), JMX (JmxMetricWriter) as seen  [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-metrics.html)

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://github.com/hengyunabc/metrics-kafka)  is what I was looking for.